# Implementing API throttling with RDB

Tags: postgresql, rdbms, throttling

I would like to implement this API throttling:

- A user can only execute the operation once per minute (once executed, following requests will be rejected for 1 minute)

The expected total number of requests from all users is around 2 per second.

I am using PostgreSQL 14.5.
I guess I will need a table for exclusive processing. What kind of SQL/algorithm should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the latest accepted timestamp in a column. Every time a request is processed, the code could check if the interval between the current timestamp and the last accepted timestamp is less than a minute and reject if so.

Comment: Without some kind lock, multiple requests will be accepted if they reach at the same time.

Comment: You can e.g. use an advisory lock. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS